# Checkers Forced Jumping

Tags: java

In my Checkers code, I am trying to make it so that whenever a piece lands in a spot where it is able to jump, it is forced to jump. In my code, it highlights the spots where you can jump. I have already made it so that you can jump other pieces and such, but I have yet to find a way to force a player to jump. Using a boolean and a method would be preferable to scan the board for a jump and disable all the tiles but the one that is jumping and the one that you will be jumping to.

**Main Class**

```
import javax.swing.*;

import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;

public class Main extends JFrame implements ActionListener
{
public Tile board[][];
private Container contentPane;
private JButton reset;
private static final Icon b =  new ImageIcon("Black.png");
private static final Icon r =  new ImageIcon("red.png");
private boolean turn1;
private boolean turn2;
private boolean jumpAvailable;
private int count = 0;

public Main()
{
    try 
    {
        // Set cross-platform Java L&F (also called "Metal")
        UIManager.setLookAndFeel(
                UIManager.getCrossPlatformLookAndFeelClassName());
    } 
    catch (UnsupportedLookAndFeelException e) {
        // handle exception
    }
    catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
        // handle exception
    }
    catch (InstantiationException e) {
        // handle exception
    }
    catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
        // handle exception
    }


    contentPane = getContentPane();
    contentPane.setLayout(null);
    setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    setTitle("Checkers");
    setSize(1430,1280);
    setResizable(false);
    contentPane.setBackground(Color.cyan.darker());

    board = new Tile[8][8];
    for(int x = 0; x < 8; x++)
    {
        for(int y = 0;  y < 8; y++)
        {
            board[x][y] = new Tile(x,y);
            board[x][y].setBounds(25 + (x*150), 25 + (y*150),150,150);
            board[x][y].addActionListener(this);
            board[x][y].setOpaque(true);
            if(x%2 == y%2)
            {
                board[x][y].setBackground(Color.BLACK);
            }
            else
            {
                board[x][y].setBackground(Color.RED);
            }
            contentPane.add(board[x][y]);
            if(x%2 == y/1 - 1)
            {
                board[x][y].setIcon(b);
            }
            if(x%2 == y/1 + 1)
            {
                board[x][y].setIcon(b);
            }
            if(x%2 == y/1 - 7)
            {
                board[x][y].setIcon(r);
            }
            if(x%2 == y/1 - 5)
            {
                board[x][y].setIcon(r);
            }
            turn1=true;
        }
    }

    reset = new JButton("Reset");
    reset.setBounds(1235,150,100,50);
    reset.addActionListener(this);
    contentPane.add(reset);

}

public static void main(String args[])
{
    Main frame = new Main();
    frame.setVisible(true);
}

public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
{
    if(e.getSource()instanceof Tile)
    {
        jumpCheck();
        Tile clicked = (Tile)e.getSource();
        if(clicked==(Tile)e.getSource())
        {
            System.out.println(clicked.getRow() + " " + clicked.getColumn());
            count++;
        }
        for(int x = 0; x < 8; x++)
        {
            for(int y = 0;  y < 8; y++)
            {
                if(turn1)
                {
                    if(clicked==board[x][y] && board[x][y].getIcon()==r && board[x][y].getBackground()==Color.red)
                    {
                        if(clicked==board[x][y] && board[x][y].getRow()!=0 && board[x-1][y-1].getIcon()==r &&board[x+1][y-1].getIcon()==r)
                        {
                            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "This piece cannot move. Please select another.");
                        }
                        else if(clicked==board[x][y] && board[x][y].getRow()==0 && board[x+1][y-1].getIcon()==r)
                        {
                            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "This piece cannot move. Please select another.");
                        }
                        else if(clicked==board[x][y] && board[x][y].getRow()==7 && board[x-1][y-1].getIcon()==r)
                        {
                            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "This piece cannot move. Please select another.");
                        }

                        else if(clicked==board[x][y] && board[x][y].getIcon()==r && board[x+1][y-1].getIcon()==b && board[x+2][y-2].getIcon()==null||clicked==board[x][y] && board[x][y].getIcon()==r && board[x-1][y-1].getIcon()==b && board[x-2][y-2].getIcon()==null)
                        {
                            if(clicked==board[x][y] && board[x][y].getIcon()==r && board[x+1][y-1].getIcon()==b && board[x+2][y-2].getIcon()==null)
                            {
                                board[x][y].setIcon(null);
                                board[x+2][y-2].setBackground(Color.white);
                            }
                            else if(clicked==board[x][y] && board[x][y].getIcon()==r && board[x-1][y-1].getIcon()==b && board[x-2][y-2].getIcon()==null)
                            {
                                board[x][y].setIcon(null);
                                board[x-2][y-2].setBackground(Color.white);
                            }
                        }

                        else
                        {
                            board[x][y].setIcon(null);
                            if(clicked==board[x][y] && clicked.getRow()==0)
                            {
                                board[x+1][y-1].setBackground(Color.white);
                            }
                            else if(clicked==board[x][y] && clicked.getRow()==7)
                            {
                                board[x-1][y-1].setBackground(Color.white);
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                board[x-1][y-1].setBackground(Color.white);
                                board[x+1][y-1].setBackground(Color.white);
                            }
                        }
                    }


                    else if(clicked==board[x][y] && board[x][y].getIcon()==null)
                    {
                        if(clicked==board[x][y] && board[x][y].getBackground()==Color.white)
                        {
                            if(clicked==board[x][y] && board[x][y].getIcon()==null && board[x][y].getBackground()==Color.black)
                            {
                                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Please choose a valid place to jump to.");
                            }



                            else if(clicked==board[x][y] && board[x+1][y+1].getIcon()==b)
                            {
                                board[x][y].setIcon(r);
                                turn1=false;
                                turn2=true;
                                board[x][y].setBackground(Color.red);
                                board[x+1][y+1].setIcon(null);
                            }

                            else if(clicked==board[x][y] && board[x-1][y+1].getIcon()==b)
                            {
                                board[x][y].setIcon(r);
                                turn1=false;
                                turn2=true;
                                board[x][y].setBackground(Color.red);
                                board[x-1][y+1].setIcon(null);
                            }

                            else if(clicked==board[x][y] && board[x][y].getBackground()==Color.red||board[x][y].getBackground()==Color.white)
                            {
                                if(count == 1)
                                {
                                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "You really should click on a piece if you want to move.");
                                    count = 0;
                                }
                                else
                                {
                                    board[x][y].setIcon(r);
                                    turn1=false;
                                    turn2=true;
                                    board[x][y].setBackground(Color.red);
                                    board[x+2][y].setBackground(Color.red);
                                    board[x-2][y].setBackground(Color.red);
                                    count = 0;
                                }
                            }
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Please choose a valid place to jump to.");
                        }
                    }


                }


                if(turn2)
                {
                    if(clicked==board[x][y] && board[x][y].getIcon()==b && board[x][y].getBackground()==Color.red)
                    {
                        if(clicked==board[x][y] && board[x][y].getRow()!=0 && board[x-1][y+1].getIcon()==b &&board[x+1][y+1].getIcon()==b)
                        {
                            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "This piece cannot move. Please select another.");
                        }
                        else if(clicked==board[x][y] && board[x][y].getRow()==0 && board[x+1][y-1].getIcon()==b)
                        {
                            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "This piece cannot move. Please select another.");
                        }
                        else if(clicked==board[x][y] && board[x][y].getRow()==7 && board[x-1][y+1].getIcon()==b)
                        {
                            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "This piece cannot move. Please select another.");
                        }

                        else if(clicked==board[x][y] && board[x][y].getIcon()==r && board[x+1][y-1].getIcon()==b && board[x+2][y-2].getIcon()==null||clicked==board[x][y] && board[x][y].getIcon()==r && board[x-1][y-1].getIcon()==b && board[x-2][y-2].getIcon()==null)
                        {
                            if(clicked==board[x][y] && board[x][y].getIcon()==r && board[x+1][y-1].getIcon()==b && board[x+2][y-2].getIcon()==null)
                            {
                                board[x][y].setIcon(null);
                                board[x+2][y-2].setBackground(Color.white);
                            }
                            else if(clicked==board[x][y] && board[x][y].getIcon()==r && board[x-1][y-1].getIcon()==b && board[x-2][y-2].getIcon()==null)
                            {
                                board[x][y].setIcon(null);
                                board[x-2][y-2].setBackground(Color.white);
                            }
                        }

                        else
                        {
                            board[x][y].setIcon(null);
                            if(clicked==board[x][y] && clicked.getRow()==0)
                            {
                                board[x-1][y+1].setBackground(Color.white);
                            }
                            else if(clicked==board[x][y] && clicked.getRow()==7)
                            {
                                board[x+1][y+1].setBackground(Color.white);
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                board[x+1][y+1].setBackground(Color.white);
                                board[x-1][y+1].setBackground(Color.white);
                            }
                        }
                    }

                    else if(clicked==board[x][y] && board[x][y].getIcon()==null)
                    {

                        if(clicked==board[x][y] && board[x][y].getBackground()==Color.white)
                        {
                            if(clicked==board[x][y] && board[x][y].getIcon()==null && board[x][y].getBackground()==Color.black)
                            {
                                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Please choose a valid place to jump to.");
                            }

                            else if(clicked==board[x][y] && board[x-1][y-1].getIcon()==r)
                            {
                                board[x][y].setIcon(b);
                                turn2=false;
                                turn1=true;
                                board[x][y].setBackground(Color.red);
                                board[x-1][y-1].setIcon(null);
                            }

                            else if(clicked==board[x][y] && board[x+1][y-1].getIcon()==r)
                            {
                                board[x][y].setIcon(b);
                                turn2=false;
                                turn1=true;
                                board[x][y].setBackground(Color.red);
                                board[x+1][y-1].setIcon(null);
                            }

                            else if(clicked==board[x][y] && board[x][y].getBackground()==Color.red||board[x][y].getBackground()==Color.white)
                            {
                                if(count == 1)
                                {
                                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "You really should click on a piece if you want to move.");
                                    count = 0;
                                }
                                else
                                {
                                    board[x][y].setIcon(r);
                                    turn2=false;
                                    turn1=true;
                                    board[x][y].setBackground(Color.red);
                                    board[x+2][y].setBackground(Color.red);
                                    board[x-2][y].setBackground(Color.red);
                                    count = 0;
                                }
                            }
                        }

                        else
                        {
                            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Please choose a valid place to jump to.");
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

private void jumpCheck()//Where I would like to do force jumping.
{
    for(int x = 0; x < 8; x++)
    {
        for(int y = 0; y < 8; y++)
        {

        }
    }
}
}
```

**End Main Class**

**Tile Class**

```
import javax.swing.*;

import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;

public class Tile extends JButton
{
public int row;
public int column;
public boolean occupied;
public Icon image;

public Tile(int x, int y)
{
    row = x;
    column = y;
    occupied = false;
    createTile(column, row, occupied);
}

public void createTile(int y, int x, boolean b)
{
    row = x;
    column = y;
    occupied = false;
}

public int setRow()
{
    switch(row)
    {
        case 0: return 1;
        case 1: return 2;
        case 2: return 3;
        case 3: return 4;
        case 4: return 5;
        case 5: return 6;
        case 6: return 7;
        case 7: return 8;
        default: return 0;
    }
}

public int getRow()
{
    return row;
}

public int setColumn() 
{
    switch(column)
    {
        case 0: return 1;
        case 1: return 2;
        case 2: return 3;
        case 3: return 4;
        case 4: return 5;
        case 5: return 6;
        case 6: return 7;
        case 7: return 8;
        default: return 0;
    }
}

public int getColumn()
{
    return column;
}

public void setPiece(Icon piece)
{
    image = piece;
}

public Icon getPiece()
{
    return image;
}

public void setOccupied(boolean b)
{
    occupied = b;
}

public boolean isOccupied()
{
    return occupied;
}
}
```

**End Tile Class**

Do you have any ideas or suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way for this i see here is that you create a new Methoc called `jump` which gets the clicked `Tile`. In this method you have your code for jumping and if you want to force the player to jump to a point you can call this method with the `Tile` you want to jump to.
Here a sample for this method with a pice of your code which i think its for the jumping:

```
private void jumpTo(Tile tileToJumpTo)
       {
          if(tileToJumpTo==board[x][y] && board[x][y].getBackground()==Color.white)
                            {
                                if(tileToJumpTo==board[x][y] && board[x][y].getIcon()==null && board[x][y].getBackground()==Color.black)
                                {
                                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Please choose a valid place to jump to.");
                                }



                                else if(tileToJumpTo==board[x][y] && board[x+1][y+1].getIcon()==b)
                                {
                                    board[x][y].setIcon(r);
                                    turn1=false;
                                    turn2=true;
                                    board[x][y].setBackground(Color.red);
                                    board[x+1][y+1].setIcon(null);
                                }

                                else if(tileToJumpTo==board[x][y] && board[x-1][y+1].getIcon()==b)
                                {
                                    board[x][y].setIcon(r);
                                    turn1=false;
                                    turn2=true;
                                    board[x][y].setBackground(Color.red);
                                    board[x-1][y+1].setIcon(null);
                                }

                                else if(tileToJumpTo==board[x][y] && board[x][y].getBackground()==Color.red||board[x][y].getBackground()==Color.white)
                                {
                                    if(count == 1)
                                    {
                                        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "You really should click on a piece if you want to move.");
                                        count = 0;
                                    }
                                    else
                                    {
                                        board[x][y].setIcon(r);
                                        turn1=false;
                                        turn2=true;
                                        board[x][y].setBackground(Color.red);
                                        board[x+2][y].setBackground(Color.red);
                                        board[x-2][y].setBackground(Color.red);
                                        count = 0;
                                    }
                                }
          }
```

I hope this answers your question an help you. :)

Btw. I would suggest you to make an own method for every operation the user can make.